# google maps everytime fails to place some markers on the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation, jquery-gmap

im trying to place like 130/140 markers on a custom google map.

i inject the map with jquery and gmaps (http://gmap.nurtext.de/)
everytime, at random (not related to specific markers) a lots of markers are not shown.

firebug report this error:

```
a is null
```

and this error comes from this file:

```
http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_ALL/mapfiles/285c/maps2.api/main.js
```

if i refresh the page...some other markers are "hidden" and other ones are shown.

anyone had this problem/can help me or suggest another safe way to show all markers?

thanks a lot!

---

EDIT:
this is how i inject the map and the markers (with a lots of address, but in this example only few)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#container").gMap(
        {
            scrollwheel: false,
            maptype: G_PHYSICAL_MAP,
            icon:
            {
                image: "files/images/gmap_pin.png",
                iconsize: [32, 37],
                iconanchor: [32, 37],
                infowindowanchor: [12, 0]
            },
            address: "Milano",
            zoom: 4,
            markers:
            [
            { address: "Viale Certosa, Milano" },
            { address: "Viale Ceccarini, Milano" },
            { address: "Viale Italia, Milano" },
            { address: "Via Rodi, Milano" },
            ]
        });
});
```

Comment: Can you upload your code so we can see more clearly the problem?

Comment: of course Argiropoulos, just edited my post ;)

Comment: I took a look and it is hard to tell what the problem is.Although irrelevant to your question i think you should use only the google-maps v3 api as v2 is deprecated and gmap uses v2.Also using plugins is more complicated than use the google javascript api directly.

Comment: How did you finally resolve the issue? (I'm facing the same problem)

Comment: Nevermind I've solved it by using another, more up-to date library. [goMaps](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/index.php) (using Gmaps api v3.3 and jquery 1.5). It is said to be the best GglMaps jQuery plugin out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in the plugin itself.
it try to get from gmaps the geocodes..but there is no callback that stop the cycled requests if there is some latency in the gmaps responses.